# Linking to external Javascript-file from .tpl does not work

Tags: javascript, html, smarty

I have a script for a navigation menu which works properly in a combination of JS, CSS and html. But if I place the html-code into a .tpl-File which uses Smarty, it doesn't work anymore, obviously the links, which refer to the external JS-files, are simply ignored:

```
<script src="menu/js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="menu/js/jquery.menu.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Am I missing something?

If I place the JS-function straight into the .tpl, it works well, but the response time of the page is pretty slow then. I have a sense that is because of the big bunch of JS-code in my .tpl-file, or does it make no difference?

Nonetheless, I think the links to external files should work somehow.

Comment: What's output to the page? If it's in the DOM, it should work. Are your paths correct?

Comment: Off topic: The `type` attribute is unnecessary in HTML5 for JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

There should be no problem with what you are doing here, but make sure that you refer to the correct placement of your JavaScript-file.

For example if the script is placed in a folder inside your `templates` directory:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='/templates/jquery/dropdown.js'></script>
```

This indicates the following placement of the file:

```
[doc_root]/templates/jquery/
```

as you do not open with "`/`" in your include-code, the code implements that the position of the file is relative to the current position.

Comment: oh what a simple thing, indeed it was the missing "/". Should be: `<script src="/menu/js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`. Thank you.